# Python script repeat

Tags: python

I have an LED strip on a raspberry and would like to indicate the status of the internet on the LED strip by means of a color.

Now I came up with this:

```
import os
hostname = "google.com" #example

response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname)

#and then check the response...

if response == 0:
    exec(open("random_blink.py").read())

else:
    exec(open("random_blink_colours.py").read())
```

How can I get the script to rerun every 10 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `time.sleep()` along with a loop:

```
import time
import os
while True:
    import os
    hostname = "google.com" #example

    response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname)

    #and then check the response...

    if response == 0:
        exec(open("random_blink.py").read())

    else:
        exec(open("random_blink_colours.py").read())

    time.sleep(10)
```

I would recommend implementing a stop condition also.

Comment: Thanks! this works!

Comment: @rvdk92 Glad to here! If this answered your question I would greatly appreciate an accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure there's a better way to do it but I would try

```
import os, time
hostname = "google.com" #example

while True:
    response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname)

    #and then check the response...

    if response == 0:
        exec(open("random_blink.py").read())
        time.sleep(10)

    else:
        exec(open("random_blink_colours.py").read())
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import os, time

hostname = "google.com"

while True:
    response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname)

    if response == 0:
        exec(open("random_blink.py","r").read())

    else:
        exec(open("random_blink_colours.py","r").read())

    time.sleep(10)
```

Should do the work

Answer (score -2):

Just use an infinite loop that sleeps for 10 seconds.

```
import subprocess
import time

...

while True:
    result = subprocess.run(["ping", "-c", "1", hostname])
    to_run = "random_blink.py" if result.returncode == 0 else "random_blink_colors.py"
    subprocess.run([to_run])
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Thank you i will try this also